# What is going wrong with my MongoDB API

Tags: mongodb

For some reason my API is not working. An err response is being sent so I can narrow the problem down to the following code.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

const connection = (closure) => {
    return MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/manatee', (err, db) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        closure(db);
    });
};

const sendError = (err, res) => {
    response.status = 501;
    response.message = typeof err == 'object' ? err.message : err;
    res.status(501).json(response);
};

let response = {
    status: 200,
    data: [],
    message: null
};

router.get('/tasks', (req, res) => {
    connection((db) => {
        db.collection('tasks').find()
            .toArray()
            .then((tasks) => {
                response.data = tasks;
                res.json(response);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                sendError(err, res);
            });
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am using mongodb ^2.2.34 . Can anyone spot the problem here? I am pretty lost as to what it could be and any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What is the error that you get? Describe the problem in detail to get help

Comment: 404. Basically it is unable to connect to MongoDB .